# Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function when importing @material-ui/pickers

Tags: material-ui

I am using `"@material-ui/core": "^3.9.3"` with `"@material-ui/pickers": "^3.0.0-beta.1"`

When I import anything from `@material-ui/pickers` I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
at Module../node_modules/@material-ui/pickers/dist/material-ui-pickers.esm.js (material-ui-pickers.esm.js:25)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:781)
at fn (bootstrap:149)
at Module../src/views/Event/Create.js (User.js:18)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:781)
at fn (bootstrap:149)
at Module../src/Routes.js (Routes.js:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:781)
at fn (bootstrap:149)
at Module../src/layouts/Admin.jsx (index.js:73)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:781)
at fn (bootstrap:149)
at Module../src/index.js (index.css?02e3:45)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:781)
at fn (bootstrap:149)
at Object.0 (Notifications.jsx:300)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:781)
at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
at main.chunk.js:1
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure that `@material-ui/pickers` is the new npm package, that serving next version. And it's required `@material-ui/core` **at least** v4.0.0-beta.0

For the old v3 version of material-ui, use `material-ui-pickers` package and version v2.2.4

Comment: Am I missing something in the docs about the required versions? Sorry, just started working with MUI.